# syntax error while using php pack() function inside class

Tags: php, function, class, syntax-error, pack

I must use **PHP pack() function** to do something in my codes. But when I do it inside a class, I get the errors below. Whereas if I use it normally (without using in class), it works without any error.

```
class encryption
{
    $my_key = pack('H*', "123456");
}
```

and this is the error:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_VARIABLE, expecting T_FUNCTION in ...
```

Also if I use `public` for `$my_key`, I will get a new error.

```
class encryption
{
    public $my_key = pack('H*', "123456");
}
```

Error:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '(', expecting ',' or ';' in ...
```

What is wrong in my codes?

Comment: man you can not use a function to set a global variable with value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When defining a variable for a class outside of a function, you can't use another function to define it.  If you need it to have that value when initialised, set the value in the constructor function.  Your class will then look like :

```
class encryption
{
    public $my_key;

    public function __construct() {
        $this->my_key = pack('H*', "123456");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
class encryption
{
    public $my_key;

    public function __construct()
    {
         $this->my_key = $this->pack('H*', "123456");
         // will always be executed when you create an object of this class
    }

    private function pack($arg1, $arg2)
    {
        // return something
    }
}
```